# How to update "complex" data stored with jQuery's .data()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

It seems to me that jQuery's `.data()` function is more of a write-once store than true read-write-storage.

There does not seem to be a comfortable way of updating complex values.

Let's suppose one wants to use some elements in a double-linked list (not my use case, illustrative purpose only).

It would be easy if I would do:

```
$elem.data('prev', $prev);
$elem.data('next', $next);
```

But I feel it is bad practice to pollute the "global" `.data()` namespace of an element.

So I would rather do:

```
$elem.data('list', {prev: $prev, next: $next});
```

But how do I now update `prev`?

In the first example, I would just do:

```
$elem.data('prev', $newPrev);
```

But in the in my opinion "nicer" way of doing things the only thing I can think of is something like this:

```
$elem.data('list', {prev: $newPrev, next: $elem.data('list').next});
```

This seems a lot more cumbersome to me and I suspect there is a better way, but so far I was unable to find anything.

How should I go about this?

Comment: What's the problem with using data('next',..) data('prev',..) ? it is per element, not global

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call jQuery's data method with one argument, you get a reference to the stored object, which you can update directly using regular `.` notation:

```
$elem.data('list').prev = $newPrev;
```

Thanks @balpha

Comment: the third line is unnecessary

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
// method one
var elemData = $elem.data("list");
elemData.prev = "foo";

// method two
$elem.data("list").next = "bar";
```

If you have FireBug you can check the demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/ExVjZ/show/) and [here](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/ExVjZ/) (output is logged in the console).